# haproxy - layer 7 health check failure

Tags: haproxy

I am getting occasional layer 7 health check failures. This happens on production machine seemingly at random, maybe once a minute or every few minutes on average. Here is the configuration:

```
backend api
    mode http
    option httpchk GET /api/v1/status HTTP/1.0
    http-check expect status 200
    balance roundrobin
    server api1 127.0.0.1:8001 check fall 3 rise 2
    server api2 127.0.0.1:8002 check fall 3 rise 2
```

The HAproxy log tells me the following:

```
Health check for server api/api2 failed, reason: Layer7 timeout, check duration: 10001ms, status: 2/3 UP.
```

Strange thing is when I run a script to fetch the same URL at a much faster pace than HAproxy, it never fails to return 200 response. It never hangs like it seems to do for HAproxy.

In addition, I'm getting occasional HAProxy error for various API calls, not just health checks, all looking quite similar:

```
https-in~ api/api1 45/0/0/-1/30045 504 194 - - sHVN 50/49/13/10/0 0/0 "POST /api/v1/accounts HTTP/1.1"
```

What could be the issue here? This one really got me stumped.

Comment: A 504 error in the logs would usually indicate that your api server took too long to send a response to HAProxy.  Do you have corresponding logs for your api server?  It might help you narrow down the problem.  Probably there's some edge case that causes your server to not respond longer than the HAProxy server timeout.  It could also be due to a bug in HAProxy itself (for example: https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/intermittent-504-errors-and-sr-after-upgrade-to-1-7-10/2029/22).  If you can't trace it to your app server, you can try upgrading HAProxy to see if it solves the issue.

Comment: there doesnt seem to be anything wrong with the API server, run with spring boot. unless there is a race condition that was overlooked which is always a possibility, and it wouldnt show any errors. still, doesnt explain why i dont get locks via script. the `/status` endpoint is an empty method how on earth could it time out

Comment: There are many possibilities why you might get a 504, for example if your api server uses a thread or worker pool and it exhausts resources, even simple `/status/` requests could be queued for long periods of time and potentially trigger a timeout.  If you have some exported metrics  or saved logs for your api server correspond to the same requests, it could help point you in the right direction.  Sorry I can't be of more help, good luck!

Comment: We have exactly the same situation here. We have multiple backends configured with 2 servers, one live, one backup and haproxy is switching between them every 10-15min. this is really annoying and I wasn't able to find a solution yet. I also did a stress test with a simple script hammering 5 requests a second but no other status than 200 occured. I would be very interested in a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You've configured `haproxy` to send health checks using `HTTP 1.0` (which is also the default).

```
GET /api/v1/status HTTP/1.0
content-length: 0
```

the `curl` equivalent would be:

```
curl --http1.0 http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/status
```

make sure you're backend server handles this correctly.

You might want to switch to `HTTP/1.1`:

```
backend api
  option httpchk GET /api/v1/status HTTP/1.1
  ...
```

For occasional failures consider retrying requests, though it might indicate some issue on the application server side (note, `haproxy >= 2.0` needed)

```
backend api
    option redispatch
    retry-on empty-response conn-failure
```

also increasing timeout for the check might help:

```
backend api
  timeout check 15s
```

Check [haproxy blog](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy-layer-7-retries-and-chaos-engineering) for more details.